# Accessing local file from vps

Tags: ubuntu, vps

I currently have an Ubuntu VPS(from Koding), I connect to it through remote desktop connection on my Windows machine. There is an option to use my local drives(belonging to my Windows machine) for the VPS, but I cannot find the drives anywhere on my VPS.

Does anyone have any idea where I can access them ?

Comment: Are you sure that "Local Drives" mean "Local to your computer" and not "Local to the machine the VPS is on"  My experience tells me the latter is a lot more likely.   Also, there is no obvious mechanism I can think of to allow the sharing of your local computer drives with the VPS server. (You should also specify the type of VPS Koding are providing you if you want better answers).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `scp` to copy files between your Windows machine and your VPS linux box.

`scp <fileYouWantToTransfer> <username>@<IP/FQDN>:/<FullURLofTargetLocation>`

Example: I want to move a file called "file1.zip" to my home directory on my VPS, here is the command:

`scp file1.zip root@79.1.11.178:/home/root` You'll be prompted to enter the password for root.